# Pushing Exploded String in Array to Another Element in Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

Here's what my array looks like

```
Array (
    [confirmshipment] => Array (

        [columndata] => Array (

            [0] => Array (

                    [0] => 
                    [1] => SG - NOUR RIBTS - CATHUPP
                    [2] => Nour Ribt Spaxacol Blenk
                    [3] => 800
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 07-72-7016
                    [6] => Ecoaxan
                    [7] => NOUR RIBTS 07-72-7016
                    [8] => 
                         )

            [1] => Array (

                    [0] => 
                    [1] => SG - NOUR RIBTS - CATHUPP
                    [2] => Nour Ribt Spaxacol Loaxal
                    [3] => 800
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 07-72-7016
                    [6] => Ecoaxan
                    [7] => NOUR RIBTS 07-72-7016
                    [8] => 

                         )

                              )

    [myCheckboxes] => 1,1
    [panelnumberx] => 0
                                )
       )
```

This is coming via a `$_POST` ajax response / `$confirmshipment = $_POST['confirmshipment'];` / `$.post( ajaxurl, { confirmshipment: {columndata,myCheckboxes,panelnumberx} }`

Now what I'm trying to do is group `myCheckboxes` with `columndata` (these will always be the same array count)

I can easily make myCheckboxes an array

```
 $checkboxes = explode(',', $params['confirmshipment']['myCheckboxes']);
```

Making a new `$checkboxes` array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
)
```

I've also tried using the `&$` reference in a foreach loop to modify the original array..

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($checkboxes as $checked) {
foreach ($params as $key['columndata'] => &$value) {
    $value['columndata']['ooscheck'][$c] = $checked;
    $c++;
}
}
```

Making it look like this

```
Array (
    [confirmshipment] => Array (

        [columndata] => Array (

            [0] => Array (

                    [0] => 
                    [1] => SG - NOUR RIBTS - CATHUPP
                    [2] => Nour Ribt Spaxacol Blenk
                    [3] => 800
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 07-72-7016
                    [6] => Ecoaxan
                    [7] => NOUR RIBTS 07-72-7016
                    [8] => 
                         )

            [1] => Array (

                    [0] => 
                    [1] => SG - NOUR RIBTS - CATHUPP
                    [2] => Nour Ribt Spaxacol Loaxal
                    [3] => 800
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 07-72-7016
                    [6] => Ecoaxan
                    [7] => NOUR RIBTS 07-72-7016
                    [8] => 

                         )

            [ooscheck] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1
                            [1] => 1
                        )

                              )

    [myCheckboxes] => 1,1
    [panelnumberx] => 0
                                )
       )
```

Also tried `array_combine` ... `$c = array_combine($params['confirmshipment']['columndata'], $checkboxes);`, but get a `Warning: array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements` error

What I'm looking to achieve is my columndata array output to look like this

```
[columndata] => Array (

    [0] => Array (

            [0] => 
            [1] => SG - NOUR RIBTS - CATHUPP
            [2] => Nour Ribt Spaxacol Blenk
            [3] => 800
            [4] => 
            [5] => 07-72-7016
            [6] => Ecoaxan
            [7] => NOUR RIBTS 07-72-7016
            [8] => 
            [9] => 1
                 )

    [1] => Array (

            [0] => 
            [1] => SG - NOUR RIBTS - CATHUPP
            [2] => Nour Ribt Spaxacol Loaxal
            [3] => 800
            [4] => 
            [5] => 07-72-7016
            [6] => Ecoaxan
            [7] => NOUR RIBTS 07-72-7016
            [8] => 
            [9] => 1
                 )

                      )
```

Noting the new array element (pushed from the checkbox array), `[9] => 1`

Or technically, since `[8] =>` will always be blank, it can be appended to this number as well.

What's my best option here to traverse and modify my array in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I do not fully understand your code, I think this should work:

```
// Loop the exploded checkboxes
foreach( $checkboxes as $k=>$v )
{
    // Since the index of the columndata matches the index of the $checkboxes
    // we can safely just add the checkbox value to that columndata position
    $params['confirmshipment']['columndata'][$k][] = $v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're literally setting the `ooscheck` key in the array which is the opposite of what it seems you're attempting to accomplish.

You can append it to the end of the array with `array_push(&$array, $value)`

docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Using your own code, this is some untested pseudo code that should be correct or extremely close.

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($checkboxes as $checked) {
    foreach ($params as $key['columndata'] => &$value) {
        array_push($value['columndata'][$c], $checked);
        $c++;
    }
}
```

This will push the `$checked` value on to the end of `$value['columndata'][$c]` rather than into a new `ooscheck` key in the `$value['columndata']` array.